# How do I find maximum change point in data columns and write this with a conditional statement

Tags: matlab, for-loop, if-statement

**MATLAB.**
I have a (2559 x 16 x 3) array named ydisplacements. I use the 'ischange' command with a specified threshold, in a loop to find points of rapid change in the data in each column, for all three planes. This I record in a logical array TF(2559 x 16 x 3) in which '1' denotes points of sharp change.
I want to have TF such that in each of its columns only the most extreme change from 'ydisplacements' is recorded in it as logical 1. In other words, everything else is a logical 0, I want only one logical 1 for each column of TF. This I can do easily by increasing the threshold till my desired outcome. But my question is how I can automate this so that for each column of ydisplacements(:,i,j), the threshold keeps increasing by a predetermined value until the desired outcome of only one logical 1 is achieved in TF, before moving to the next index.
I have tried this code below. Any help is appreciated.
Thank you..

```
increment = 100;
for i = 1:size(ydisplacements,2);
    for j = 1:size(ydisplacements,3);
        threshold = 100;
        TF(:,i,j) = ischange(ydisplacements(:,i,j),'Linear','Threshold',threshold);
        if sum(TF(:,i,j) == 1)>1; 
            threshold = threshold + increment;
            TF(:,i,j) = ischange(ydisplacements(:,i,j),'Linear','Threshold',threshold);
        else
            threshold = threshold;
            TF(:,i,j) = ischange(ydisplacements(:,i,j),'Linear','Threshold',threshold);
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% sure without an example data. But it is very likely using if-else statment will only increment the threshold once. What I would do is using a while-loop as a unlimited iterative if statement. Something like:

```
increment = 100;
for i = 1:size(ydisplacements,2);
    for j = 1:size(ydisplacements,3);
        threshold = 100;
        TF(:,i,j) = ischange(ydisplacements(:,i,j),'Linear','Threshold',threshold);
        while sum(TF(:,i,j) == 1)>1  % Iterate always sum(TRUEs) > 1
            threshold = threshold + increment;
            TF(:,i,j) = ischange(ydisplacements(:,i,j),'Linear','Threshold',threshold);
         end
    end
end
```

The while-loop should iterate until there's only 1 `TRUE` value in TF(:,i,j), so then it check again `sum(TF(:,i,j) == 1)>1`, returns `FALSE` and continue to the next iteration of the nested 2-for-loops.

But, as I said, this is my idea and I can't be sure without an example of your matrix. By the way, probably there are better ways to get the most extreme change rather than using nested for-loops.

Comment: Thanks @RobertoT, this solved my problem. I'll be grateful if you can point me to where I can find such better ways you mentioned?

Comment: @ChiddyBrendan Not sure right now, because I've never used `ischange()` function. But looking to the documentation, you can get more outputs saying `[TF,S1,S2] = ischange(___)`. S1 is the mean of the segment and S2 the variance of the segment. So perhaps it will be much faster just calling the function once instead of the while loop and looking to S2 to see the greater variance. Then you save time.

Comment: @ChiddyBrendan Also you could try other ways such as median filters or percentage? filter (I'm not sure of the name of this last one, but it is basically calculating differences from previous and dividing by mean or median or sthing like that. Then you got weights of changes in values).

Comment: Thank you. I'll go through the documentation again, more thoroughly